# Output Contents of PHP File for a GET/POST request

Tags: php, xml, file-io

I have a script which generates an XML file when the user accesses the link like so:

> **domain.com/dirList.php**

I would like to print the contents of the XML to the user at the end of the POST or GET request (have not implemented this yet). At the moment I am just viewing the link through a web browser.

This is the code I am using to print the file contents.

```
# Open XML file and print contents
$filename = "test.xml";
$handle = fopen ($filename, "r"); 
$contents = fread ($handle, filesize ($filename)); 
fclose ($handle); 
print $contents;
```

The problem is that it doesn't seem to be working. I think I might be either missing a header like this: `("Content-Type: text/xml");` or maybe my code is wrong.

What do I need to do to get the XML file to print to the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just do:

```
header('Content-type: text/xml'); // set the correct MIME type before you print.
readfile('test.xml'); // output the complete file.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Check there is any extra space before <? and after ?>

//or 

header('Content-type: text/xml');
echo file_get_contents($path.$xmlfile);
```